# "syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end" while executing a daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

UPDATED: I used daemon_generator in a Rails 2.3 app to create a daemon. Per Jeff Perrin's suggestions below i created the following configuration. I updated this question with the final solution for others that are struggling to get a daemon working.

For debugging purposes I cut my lib/pulse_check_email.rb file down to this:

```
class PulseCheckEmail
    def self.send_pulse_check_mail
         # removed all conditional statements and other "stuff" to debug
    end
end
```

My lib/daemons/mailer.rb file:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment"
require 'pulse_check_email'

while($running) do
  PulseCheckEmail.send_pulse_check_mail
  sleep 300 # 5 min
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether you *can* call a controller method from a daemon in your Rails application, this is not something I would recommend. I would suggest that you extract the code that is currently in the `send_mail` action of the controller into a separate class (that could be put in the /lib directory as well). Then you can call that code from both your daemon and your controller.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def create
    do_stuff
    send_email
  end

  def send_email
    ExtractedClass.do_stuff(params)
  end
end

#new class in lib/extracted_class.rb
class ExtractedClass
  def self.do_stuff(params)
    #put the code that was previously in the send_email
    #function of your controller
  end
end

#in lib/daemons/mailer.rb
while($running) do
  ExtractedClass.do_stuff(params)
  sleep 300 # 5 min
end
```

This will do several things:

- You can more easily test the ExtractedClass separately
- Your daemon is just concerned with how often it should run, and what it should be running. There is no other logic necessary. You now have a *thin* daemon.
- You are moving logic out of the controller, also making it *thinner* (google "skinny controller fat model")

Comment: Thanks for this! I am building it into my code now. Will acknowledge this as the correct answer when i get it working. In the meantime, +1 for very helpful!

Comment: Hi Jeff. I used your suggestion with exception of the controller code. I don't need to access the code except for the daemon. Not sure why "ExtractedClass" would come up as an uninitialized constant.

Comment: It would most likely need to be 'required' from within your daemon. require 'extracted_class'

Comment: +1 good catch. That got rid of part of the error. See update.

Comment: rb:5: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end> is a compilation error in ruby. I've updated my answer to fix it. Stick a 'def' in front of self.send_pulse_check_mail